# How to create a MenuItemImage with a callback function in stead of selected image?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have a MenuItemImage here:

```
auto myImage = MenuItemImage::create("image.png","image_selected.png",
                         CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::onImageClicked,this));
```

It allow me to input a `image.png`, which will be changed to `image_selected.png` on selected when I navigate between items in my menu with keyboard. However, **I want to perform some actions when select it with `myImage->selected();`** (**NOT** activate it by clicking/touching or calling for myImage->activate(); function), not just a boring `image_selected.png`.

Now, I'm thinking about set up all of those action in:

```
keyBoardListener->onKeyPressed = [&](cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode keycode, Event* event)
    { // Setting up actions on KEY_RIGHT_ARROW or KEY_LEFT_ARROW pressed};
```

However this way makes things complicated. Therefore, I want to ask if there's any way that I could set up all of my actions as `myImage` being creating so I could call all of those action with a simple `myImage->selected()` or stop them with `myImage->unselected()` later?
Your attention and help is very much appreciated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
auto myImage = MenuItemImage::create("image.png", "image_selected.png", [&](Ref* ref){
//your code here
//by ref you can access "myImage" object
});
```

edit:

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. Do you want to have a few buttons in menu, which always one of the is selected and change them using arrows? (so menu navigation is like on console games).

edit2:

After watch a sample yt video I don't think you can achieve this relying only on MenuItemImage. Instead I'd create a ui::Button (if you need clicking/touching as well) or Sprite. Then I'd handle button states by myself. As for glowing frame you probably need some fancy shader or create it in photoshop and add to it an action with constantly fading out and in.

Comment: Hi @Makalele, thanks for your reply. However, I trying to performs actions on myImage **selected** (using keyboard listener in my case) by calling function `myImage->selected()`. The lambda above only works if I **activate** it with touch/click or calling function `myImage->activate()`.

In the above code, If i call for function myImage->selected(), it only shows `image_selected.png` image.

Comment: You got my idea. For more specific, I'm trying to make a menu likes this video at 1m : `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJSlvhDbB4I&feature=youtu.be&t=1m` . As you notice, there's a glowing blue line around the item, which I'm trying to do. Now lets say, I use the above code to achive this, I want to add a callback function doing those glowing things when an item is **selected** (with `myImage->selected()`) in stead of just show `image_selected.png` .  The lambda will be used to open the app on activated with **myImage->activated()**.